# Case when condition then run Query1 else Query2

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to conditionally run either of two queries based upon the existence of data.  Here is what I am trying to run.  How do I parse a table to determine if my customer contains an address, then run Query1 if it does, run Query2 if it doesn't?

Example:

```
If (Transaction_Table.Customer_Ship_To = NULL) 
then
    -- run Query1 with select
else
    -- run Query2 with select
end
```

Comment: You need a semi-colon on the end of `end;`. Otherwise this is correct in PL/SQL.

Comment: What exactly (with sample data/desired results) are you trying to do?  You may be able to combine into a single query, or you may not -- just depends...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and then update your question with the proper details. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
if((select count(*) from Transaction_Table where isnull(Customer_Ship_To))>0) then
  query1
else
  query2
end if;
```